# Comparing two symbolic expressions

Tags: equation-solving, expression-manipulation

Does *Mathematica* provide any way to compare two symbolic expressions and find which is the greatest? For example, I want to find which is the greatest of `(n - 1) + 2(n - 1) Log[2, n]` or `n(n - 1)/2`, where `n` is a variable.

Comment: You mean Log2 (with a capital L), right?

Answer (score 7):

```
Reduce[(n - 1) + 2 (n - 1) Log2[n] > n (n - 1)/2, n, Reals]
```

Returns that the statement is true for $$0 < n < \frac{-4}{\ln 2} \text{ProductLog}(\frac{-\ln 2}{4 \sqrt{2}})\lor 
 1 < n < \frac{-4}{\ln 2}\text{ProductLog}(\frac{-\ln 2}{4 \sqrt{2}})^*$$
Where $\text{ProductLog}$ is the solution to the Lambert W equation.  As @Rojo notes in the comments, use `N` to find a numerical approximation.

General note: try using the free-form input in MMA to get a primary understanding for individual functions themselves and to learn of knew ones, such as `Reduce`.

Comment: Wrap it in `N` to get `0. < n < 0.814262 || 1. < n < 18.9881`

Comment: A couple of pics: `Plot[{(n - 1) + 2 (n - 1) Log2[n], n (n - 1)/2}, {n, -.2, 1.5},
 GridLines -> {{0.814262, 1}, {}}];
Plot[{(n - 1) + 2 (n - 1) Log2[n], n (n - 1)/2}, {n, -.2, 20},
 GridLines -> {{0.814262, 1, 18.9981}, {}}]`